# PHP tcpdf small QR Code?

Tags: php, tcpdf, qr-code

Is it possible to change the size of the qr code generated from tcpdf? It seems when I change the size from anything but 50,50 points, the resulting QR code becomes invalid

Tried both variations - the QR code generated can't be read by a QR reader

`$pdf->write2DBarcode($url, 'QRCODE,H', '', '', 25, 25, $style, 'N',FALSE);`

`$pdf->write2DBarcode($url, 'QRCODE,H', '', '', 25, 25, $style, 'N',TRUE);`

Comment: Did you ever see the qr code change each time the page is reloaded?  I just asked a question here about that and am getting no responses.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be sure that your generated QR-code is large enough to be readable.
Check the TCPDF website at http://www.tcpdf.org and consult the official forum for further information.